# get csrf token from page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to extract the csrf token from a Django powered webpage using javascript.

My html template looks like this:

```
<div class = "debugging">
  <p id = "csrf">{% csrf_token %}</p>
</div>
```

When I use this script below, I can see the token value in the console, but can't actually extract it:

```
<script>
var csrfToken = document.getElementById("csrf");
console.log(csrfToken.innerHTML);
</script>
```

It returns in console:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" 
value="AAIawsx1XysoQpDyIqyzdPe3npopNCHRzFBQdvUdlr4TUPEq3Sr5C5bFqc">
```

So I tried:

```
var csrfToken = document.getElementById("csrf").attributes[0].value;
var csrfToken = document.getElementById("csrf").value;
```

both returned "undefined"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your django seems to create an input element holding your token, so just select that using `querySelector` and read its `value`:

```
var csrfToken = document.querySelector("#csrf input").value;
```

Since your django code also generates a `name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"` on that input element, you can also do this:

```
var csrfToken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in new Laravel. it is Vanilla JS and can be called anywhere. In JS or blade file.

```
var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have used
`{{ csrf_token }}`
instead of
`{% csrf_token %}`
if you intend to get only the token value